# Displaying "Empty" record templates in ASP.NET Listview

Tags: c#, asp.net, listview

I'm currently coding a web application using ASP.NET. So far my use of ASP.NET and the application has been going great, however there is one feature I would love to have, but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to do it.

I want to use some sort of list/form view, which will show both data records and empty blank templates. For example, I want to use this as an "event booking" system, where the user would click an open slot and this would then be registered to our database. This open slot is the empty template I would like.

I've done a quick paint picture to illustrate what I mean:

[image: http://imgur.com/EBKx2ks]

I assume that I'm in the right direction using a ListView, but I would like some feedback/help on a better method to achieve this.

This is my listview code (it is somewhat basic, barebones almost):

```
<asp:ListView ID="LV_AvailableUpdateSlots" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="itemPlaceholder">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceHolder" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <EmptyDataTemplate>No data for this date.</EmptyDataTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Panel ID="Pnl_AvailableSlot" runat="server" CssClass="UpdateDiarySlotPanel">
            <div class="FloatLeftInline">
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_ClientName" runat="server" Text="Name: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_ClientNameEval" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("RefID") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
            <asp:Label ID="Lbl_ClientProductEval" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("ClientMainProductID") %>'></asp:Label>
            <div class="FloatRightInline">
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_Version" runat="server" Text="Version: "></asp:Label>
                <asp:Label ID="Lbl_VersionEval" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("Version") %>'></asp:Label>
            </div>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <InsertItemTemplate>
        Insert here.
    </InsertItemTemplate>
    <EmptyItemTemplate>No data found.</EmptyItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Comment: What happens when the user clicks on one of the "Free" slots?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Sorry, I should have said!

When a user clicks one of the free slots it would either assign a user ID (defined beforehand) to that specific event time slot.

EDIT: Also, I don't have much relevant code in my opinion, but I will post it anyway. It is your basic list view code. I'm more looking for guidance on what way to proceed :)

Comment: I think a `ListView` is perfectly acceptable for what you are trying to achieve. I would pursue this approach until you run into a problem with it and then post a question here about your particular issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A **ListView** sounds good, but I does not hurt to take a look at **Repeater**

[Repeater Web Server Control Declarative Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c012haty%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)

If you have the time do a simple test implementing using a  ListView and a Repeater to compare the benefits and see which one fits better your needs and appearance